# RAW socket send: packet loss

Tags: sockets, send, loss

During the RAW-socket based packet send testing, I found very irritating symptoms. 
With a default RAW socket setting (especially for SO_SNDBUF size),
the raw socket send 100,000 packets without problem but it took about 8 seconds
to send all the packets, and the packets are correctly received by the receiver process.
It means about 10,000 pps (packets per second) is achieved by the default setting.
(I think it's too small figure contrary to my expectation.)

Anyway, to increase the pps value, I increased the packet send buffer size 
by adjusting the /proc/sys/net/core/{wmem_max, wmem_default}.
After increasing the two system parameters, I have identified the irritating symptom.
The 100,000 packets are sent promptly, but only the 3,000 packets are 
received by the receiver process (located at a remote node).

At the sending Linux box (Centos 5.2), I did netstat -a -s and ifconfig.
Netstat showed that 100,000 requests sent out, but the ifconfig shows that 
only 3,000 packets are TXed.

I want to know the reason why this happens, and I also want to know 
how can I solve this problem (of course I don't know whether it is really a problem).

Could anybody give me some advice, examples, or references to this problem?

Best regards,
bjlee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what size your packets were or any characteristics of your network, NIC, hardware, or anything about the remote machine receiving the data.

I suspect that instead of playing with /proc/sys stuff, you should be using [ethtool](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ethtool) to adjust the number of ring buffers, but not necessarily the size of those buffers.

Also, [this page](http://www.ece.rice.edu/~willmann/teng_nics_hownicswork.html) is a good resource.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment.
I have tried the ethtool -G rx 4096 tx 4096 and 
observed the tx troughput is doubled.
But the most noticeable enhancement was achieved
by /sbin/ifconfig eth1 txqueuelen 65536.
With this setting, the tx throughput was maximized 
(about 70,000 packets are TXed within 0.16 second).

Thank you!

Comment: Just curious, but doesn't a lot of that eat into kernel memory or memory that can't swapped.  Just wondering what the tradeoff is, otherwise we'd all want the Linux kernel to be pre-tuned to what you did.

Comment: I agree. But I don't know the tradeoff. I need a comment from kernel experts.

Answer (score 1):

I have just been working with essentially the same problem. I accidentally stumbled across an entirely counter-intuitive answer that still doesn't make sense to me, but it seems to work.

I was trying larger and larger `SO_SNDBUF` buffer sizes, and losing packets like mad. By accidentally overrunning my system defined maximum, it set the `SO_SNDBUF` size to a very small number instead, but oddly enough, I no longer had the packet loss issue. So I intentionally set `SO_SNDBUF` to `1`, which again resulted in a very small number (not sure, but I think it actually set it to something like `1k`), and amazingly enough, still no packet loss.

If anyone can explain this, I would be most interested in hearing it. In case it matters, my version of `Linux is RHEL 5.11` (yes, I know, I'm a bit behind the times).

Comment: I was looking at something similar and when I increased the `SO_SNDBUF` I lost packets. In my case, the receiving side was a microntroller. My theory is that when the `SNDBUF` is large, the processor waits some time for the buffer to fill up and then sends multiple of them in a burst mode. The microcontroller wasnt handling the burst. When I reduced the `SNDBUF` to 1, the packet was sent out as soon as generated and the micro was able to keep up with the individual packets.